# gg-plot isnt producing bars on the Bar chart

Tags: r

I have used the following code

```r
ggplot(IncomeGroup_count, 
  aes(x=Income_Group, 
      y= Percentage, 
      colour = 'lightblue'))
```

But the only thing it produces is the x and y axis with no bars.

Comment: You need to add a geom (e.g. geom_point() for points or geom_line() for lines) for ggplot() to actually present anything

Comment: For bars you'd want `geom_bar()`. If you want us to provide a full code example of how to get bars on your graph then you'd have to provide a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `geom_bar` function. Typically `ggplot` works as the base function for fitting whatever data you are using and then the `geom` functions "draw" the plot using that data. Here I have constructed a bar plot using data in R since you have not supplied your own data in your question.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Plot ####
airquality %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=is.na(Ozone)))+
  geom_bar()
```

Which gives you this bare bones bar plot. It takes the NA values from the `airquality` dataset, then draws bars thereafter plotting the NA values by "TRUE" for NA and "FALSE" for not NA:

[image]

#### Edit

Again it's difficult to guess what is going wrong if you don't share your data, so I'm assuming based off your comments below that you are trying to plot y explicitly as a count. As suggested in the comments, `geom_col` may be better for this. Using a different example from the same dataset:

```
airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(Mean_Ozone = mean(Ozone, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Month,
             y=Mean_Ozone))+
  geom_col()
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: Incomegroup_count_2014%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Income_Group, y=Number)) +
  geom_bar()

Comment: this code is returning an error message

Comment: Error in `f()`:
! stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

Comment: you could try ```geom_col()``` instead. You use ```geom_col()``` when you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, in your case the ```Percentage``` or ```Number``` variables that you mention

Comment: @GeorgiaBingham I've edited my answer to attempt to help.